# See Eclipse Run Configurations in a View

Tags: eclipse

I have a lot of Eclipse run configurations that I frequently access during my daily work (things like doing a maven clean build for various projects, running a test gui, deploying apps etc etc). The Run Configurations Window (accessed via Run->Run Configurations) is reasonably good and supplies me with most of my needs, but:

1. I hate having to manually open it up every time I need to run something.
2. The window is modal and that I can't easily access other Eclipse features while editing a configuration.
3. It loses any filters that I have applied previously.

Is there a way to have this window fixed in a view that I can access at any time, and that it maintains my context? It really seems to me that this feature was designed with little regard for the "Eclipse way of doing things".

I know about setting configurations up as "favourites", but I have probably close to a hundred of these configurations, and the favourites menu is simply not designed for that amount.

Comment: Yes its painful. Don't have any tips here. I think we need one plug-in to address these issues. Also there is no keyboard short-cut to open **Run/Debug configurations** pull down menu.Waiting for more comments/answers here.